# I want to search for multiple word in a search bar

Tags: php

like my title say i want to search for 1 or multiple word in a search bar . i want to be able to search for (The entire search , the 1st word , the 2nd word or the 3rd word).the way i did it i can do it if the $searchArray[0], $searchArray[1] and $searchArray[2] are defined . the problem is i cant search for les than 3 word. here is my code :

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) AND !empty($_GET['search']) AND $_GET['search'] != ' '){
$search = htmlspecialchars($_GET['search']);
$searchArray = explode(' ',$search);
var_dump($searchArray);

$totalVideosReq = $stdb->query('SELECT id FROM videos WHERE title LIKE "%'.$search.'%" OR title LIKE "%'.$searchArray[0].'%" OR title LIKE "%'.$searchArray[1].'%"');
$totalVideos = $totalVideosReq->rowcount();
$totalPages = ceil($totalVideos/$videosPerPage);
$videos = $stdb->query('SELECT id, title, videoTime FROM videos WHERE title LIKE "%'.$search.'%" OR title LIKE "%'.$searchArray[0].'%" OR title LIKE "%'.$searchArray[1].'%" ORDER BY id DESC limit '.$start.','.$videosPerPage);



$currentPage = 1;
if(isset($_GET['page']) AND !empty($_GET['page']) AND $_GET['page'] > 0 AND $_GET['page'] <= $totalPages){
$_GET['page'] = intval($_GET['page']);
$currentPage = $_GET['page'];
}else{
    $currentPage = 1;
}}
```

if you guys know how i could make it even better by searching combination of the 3 word first that would be great . Thank you in advance !

Comment: Build the query dynamically, also use parameterized queries, this is open to SQL injections. (htmlspecialchars could hinder a XSS injections, it has no affect on SQL injections).

Comment: I think i figured it out ! You need to use : mysql_real_escape_string but do you need htmlspecialchar too ?

Comment: Are you using `mysql_*`? Parameterized queries are the best method to secure yourself from SQL injections. The variables don't go in the query, you let the driver escape and quote them.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
$query = 'SELECT id FROM videos WHERE title LIKE "%'.$search.'%"'
foreach ($searchArray as $s) {
    $query .= ' OR title LIKE "%'.$s.'%"';
}
$totalVideosReq = $stdb->query($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `implode()` to generate the query dynamically, instead of hard coding it.

```
$totalVideosReq = $stdb->query('SELECT id FROM videos WHERE title LIKE "%'.$search.'%" OR title LIKE "%'.implode("\" OR title LIKE \"%", $searchArray).'%"');
```

This is vulnerable to SQL injection by the way, you need to prevent that.

Comment: thank you for your answer it work great ! do you know how i could securise my code from SQL injection ?

Comment: Prepared statements and sanitizing user inputs, theres plenty of guides on the internet (and even on SO).

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code,

```
if(count($searchArray) > 0) {
   $query = 'SELECT id FROM videos WHERE ';
   $cond = array();
   foreach ($searchArray as $s) {
      $cond[] = ' title LIKE "%'.$s.'%"';
   }
   $cond = implode(' OR ', $cond);

   //this is your query to get total videos
   $totalVideosReq = $stdb->query($query.$cond);

   //this is your query to fetch videos
   $videos = $stdb->query($query.$cond.' ORDER BY id DESC limit '.$start.','.$videosPerPage);
}
```